# On select action by selecting country flag

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, onselect

I'm using a `selectbox` on a Bootstrap platform to list multiple country flags that can be selected. On `select` the URL should be changed to the page of the country.

However, since I am not using `<option> values`, I don't know how to accomplish this. When I do work with `<option>` the flags won't display as shown below. Does anyone know how to add `on select` for this function?

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries pull-left" data-flags="true" data-country="NL" data-flags="true" data-blank="false" data-available="NL,BE">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bfh-selectbox').on('change.bfhselectbox', function () {

        if($(this).val()=="something"){
            window.location.href="http://www.somelink.com";
        }
        else if($(this).val()=="somethingelse"){
            window.location.href="http://www.someotherlink.com";
        }
        else {
        }
   });
});
```